# Accessing Objects in an LinkedList

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

Im trying to create a shopping program where customers are `objects` assigned with a customer number(given at creation).

**Class descriptions**.
The two classes seen bellow are; *Customer* and *CustomerFactory*. The *customer* class, is being used to create customers (`objects`) and assigning them with an individual customer number(*customerNumber*). *CustomerFactory* is responsible for creating the customers and putting them into an Array.

**The Problem**.
Arises when I try retrieving the *customerNumber* from respective customer using the *getNumber* method located in the Customer class. It results in the error: `Cannot resolve method 'getNumber' in 'Object'`, on line 7: ".getNumber". I need to be able to get the customer numbers to, later on, display them as output.

**The CustomerFactory class:**

```
1  public class CustomerFactory {
2
3     FIFO f = new FIFO();
4
5     public void createCustomer(){
6        f.add(new Customer(1));
7        f.Q.get(1).getNumber();
8
9     }  
10 }
```

**The Customer class:**

```
1 public class Customer {
2
3    public int customerNumber;
4
5    public Customer(int customerNumber){
6        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
7
8    }
9
10    public int getNumber(){
11        return this.customerNumber;
12
13    }
14 }
```

**FIFO class:**

```
public class FIFO {

    LinkedList<Customer> Q = new LinkedList<Customer>();

    public Object get(int number){
        return Q.get(number);
    }

    public void add(Customer o){
        Q.add(o);
    }

}
```

If there are any suggestions on how I can make this problem or anything else that you see more efficient, lmk.

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: It should `LinkedList<Customer> Q = new LinkedList< Customer>()`
since `getNumber` is method `Customer`

Comment: Do you have to use a LinkedList?  If you know each customer will have a unique identifier, I would suggest putting them into a Map<Integer, Customer>, then you can lookup then up by ID and not iterate through a list.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks! I'll look into using a Map instead.

Comment: How does the `FIFO` class look like? Is it backed by a `LinkedList`?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the answer AP11 gave answered my question. But what do you mean by backed?

Comment: @TheBigChung  So you are not interesting to explore this topic any further? Backed by a LinkedList means built on top of a LinkedList.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko The ```LinkedList``` resides in the ```FIFO``` class used to store the customers. Well, my problem was partly solved, but if there is a more effective way to do what I'm trying to accomplish(like using something other than a ```LinkedList```) then I'd be more than happy to know.

Comment: @TheBigChung In order to tell which collection is the most appropriate for your purposes, I need to know what operations you want to perform on a collection of customers? For instance, retrieve a customer by id, remove a customer with the given id, etc. For that, it'll be great to see the code of the `FIFO` class. If it's not fully implemented yet, then describe **all the cases** of how it is going to be used.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Oh, must have missed removing it when posting here, it was just a placeholder for another parameter.

Comment: @TheBigChung Ok, its not important. Please, look at my message right above yours. In order to give a suggestion, I need to see at least method declarations from the `FIFO` class (or detailed description of these methods).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I've now added the FIFO class and the methods it has that are being used by the CustomerFactory class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are casting the `LinkedList` as a list containing of `Object` not `Customer` (also not sure, why would you use LinkedList, but ok).

```
LinkedList<Customer> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then you might be getting `NullPointerException`, because you are trying to access object with index 1 in this list, but the `Customer` you create and add to the list `Q` is on index **0**.

```
public void createCustomer(){
    f.add(new Customer(1, null));
    f.Q.get(0).getNumber();
}
```

And last but not least, read about *Encapsulation*, don't just access other class variables by making them *public*.

Comment: Thanks! what would you suggest instead of a LinkedList?

Answer (score 0):

Your LinkedList should not be of type `Object`, it should have the generic type of `Customer`

```
LinkedList<Customer> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

I suggest you'd read a bit about generics in Java, it will help you understand how to handle it better